# How to create Last 12 months flag for grouped data in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I have a table where where I want to create last 12 months flag column from the latest date available in each country. I have tried many Dax formula without success.
My table looks like below:

[image]

Here Y indicates the dates falls under last twelve months.
Please help me to find this flag.

Comment: If you don't want a SQL solution, remove the SQL tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a calculated column to validate the date falls within the last 12 months, for each country.  First calculate the maxDate for each country, then ensure the date is greater than the MaxDate with an if statement

```
Last 12 Months = 
VAR  MaxDate =  CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Country[Date] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Country', 'Country'[Country] )
    )

RETURN 
    IF (
        Country[Date]> DATE(YEAR(MaxDate)-1, Month(MaxDate), Day(MaxDate)) ,1,0
    )
```

This will then give you a filterable column to work from

[image: Last 12 month flag]

Comment: latest month is not today's date.it will start from the latest month available in the country.So there will be different end date and start date depending on the country and data available

Comment: If I am using this formula and  if I am selecting two countries in the filter ,only one country's L12M data will be seen

Comment: have updated the dax example to consider country for you faisal